# How do I get rid of this memory leak in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, memory, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to find out why the following code has a memory leak:

```
module Main where

import System.IO

func :: Int -> Int -> ([Int], Int)
func input 0 = ([], input)
func input numTimes = do
    let (rest, ret) = func (input + 1) (numTimes - 1)
    ((input : rest), ret)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering
    let (list, final) = func 0 10000000000
        listStr = map (\x -> (show x) ++ "\n") list
    putStr (foldr (++) "" listStr)
    putStr (show final)

printStrs :: [String] -> String -> IO ()
printStrs [] str = do
    putStrLn str
printStrs (first : rest) str = do
    putStr first
    printStrs rest str
```

When I compile it with `ghc --make Main` and run it, the top command shows it eating up more and more memory even though the amount of memory it uses should be constant because of lazy evaluation. I've tried using the printStrs function I wrote instead, and it still eats up all memory. I've tried using ghci on the code and using :sprint to print out the thunks from func and it seems like the thunks aren't increasing the amount of memory used for each evaluation of an element in the list.

I honestly don't know what else to do.

Comment: I suspect `let (rest, ret)` might force the program to run `func` enough to unpack the rest and ret - which makes it run all the way to the end!

Comment: Just compile with `-O2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `func` will build a huge list and laziness will not be able to avoid it. It reminds me of [continuation passing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style) where the order of computations are sequentialized.

I think, the part with `foldr` is responsible for the memory consumption. By avoiding it and compiling it with `ghc -O3`, the memory usage is constant in my test:

```
module Main where

import System.IO

func :: Int -> Int -> ([Int], Int)
func input 0 = ([], input)
func input numTimes = do
    let (rest, ret) = func (input + 1) (numTimes - 1)
    ((input : rest), ret)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering
    let (list, final) = func 0 10000000000
    mapM_ (putStrLn . show) list
    putStr (show final)
```

In ghci, it still blows the memory. But it might be because the interpreter is not able to optimize the recursion away.

Comment: I'm not building the entire thing up front. It's lazily evaluation the list, but it still eats up more and more memory as time goes on. It prints out every value from the list one at a time, but it also takes up more and more memory for some reason.

Comment: @NoahWilliams It is lazily built, yes. So, it will be built as it gets printed. But I what I meant is once a value has been printed, it will not be freed but still remains referenced by the list, which will grow over time and eventually blow up the memory.

Comment: Is there some sort of better way to do this that's still mostly functional? I just want to get intermediate values so I can have some idea of how much progress the program is making and then take the final value as a separate return value.

Comment: @NoahWilliams Well, not sure. I think, if you want to (conceptually) keep a log of the intermediate values, it is hard to avoid to keep then in memory somehow. You can use debugging tools like "trace" to print intermediate values (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.3.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html). That can be useful to track down bugs. Otherwise, the imperative style (I added examples) is the best that I can think of.

Comment: @NoahWilliams I missed that you are using foldr. That is relevant. Will update my answer: there is a way to fix the memory leak directly.

Comment: regarding foldr: but `(++)` is not strict on its second argument

Comment: @user253751 You are correct. I removed that misleading part, as it is not the right explanation. Perhaps it is rather something like in this blog post: https://www.tweag.io/blog/2021-11-04-haskell-profiling-cachegrind/ But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You mention in a comment that

> I just want to get intermediate values so I can have some idea of how much progress the program is making and then take the final value as a separate return value

Let's try defining a special-purpose datatype which models the idea of "inspect some bit of progress, or get hold of the final result, if we have finished".  Something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
data Progress a r = Emit a (Progress a r) | Result r
    deriving Functor -- maps over the result value r, not over the as
```

Notice that, unlike `([Int], Int)`, `Progress` doesn't give us "direct" access to the final result until we have gone trough all the nested `Emit` constructors. Hopefully this will help us avoid unexpected dependencies between thunks.

Now let's define `func` like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
func :: Int -> Int -> Progress Int Int
func input 0 = 
    Result input
-- the bang avoids the accumulation of thunks behind the input param
func !input numTimes = 
    Emit input (func (input + 1) (numTimes - 1))
```

Notice that we don't need to go through all the recursive calls to get hold of the first progress "notification". Even if `input` is `10000000000`, we can pattern-match on the outermost `Emit` constructor after the first iteration!

The disadvantage of the `Progress a r` datatype is that we can't easily use regular list functions to print the progress. But we can define our own:

```
printProgress :: Show a => Progress a r -> IO r
printProgress (Result r) = 
    pure r
printProgress (Emit a rest) = 
    do print a
       printProgress rest
```

In practice, we often also want to be able to perform monadic effects at each "step". At that point, it's common to turn to some streaming library like [streaming](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming). If you squint a little, the [`Stream`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.1/docs/Streaming.html#t:Stream) type from "streaming" and similar libraries is basically an effectful list which returns a special result after reaching the end.